# Please help to identify burnt element with markings `AC` or `A0`, and `9C`

Tags: transistors, voltage-regulator, identification, sot23

Looks like a voltage regulator with marking `AC` or `A0`, and `9C` on perpendicular to the SOT23 element corpus length.

What it might be?

[image: Element]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Best guess: BJT due to 1 kohm on base. If you probe and trace out what pin 2 and pin 3 goes to, we can perhaps narrow down further.

Comment: It looks nothing like a voltage regulator? I'd say it rather looks like a diode, BJT or MOSFET.

Comment: The SO8 might be a voltage regulator however, given the inductor next to it.

Comment: Why do you say this looks like a voltage regulator? Is there something on the other side that gives you that idea? Show it, if so.

Comment: I updated with new photos

Comment: This site might help https://www.s-manuals.com/smd .  There are hits for both A0 & 9C.  The PNP transistor look possible https://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/b/c/bc856-bc860_fairchild.pdf , but you'd want to map out the schematic.

Comment: @AntonMiroshnichenko If you see "Q" on the silkscreen, e.g., "Q1", it indicates that it is a transistor. ICs such as voltage regulators would normally use "U" or "IC".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part [AO3400](https://s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/a/o/ao3400_r8_ao.pdf), a MOSFET, has the A0 main marking, and a lot marking just where you can see 9C (p6 in the datesheet).

Trace widths make sense, with thick for D & S, and thin for gate with a 1K gate drive resistor.

Also the datasheet specifically calls it out for "load switch" or in "PWM applications", which is what it looks like we have here, especially as the gate drive is coming from the main IC, and the D & S connections match with where the main supply wires come in.

As it would be the main current carrying element in a converter/regulator, it is a natural component to overheat if the output was shorted or excessive load drawn.

Finally it is an "economy grade" component, which fits with other parts we can identify.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: Glad to help.  If you replace the component as suggested, and it works, can you please confirm the part identification?